# Unable to reconnect to WLAN on Ubuntu 21.10 (initial connect works!)

Tags: wireless, acer, 21.10, aspire

I have an [ASUS Aspire 5 (A514-54-78HZ)](https://www.acer.com/ac/de/CH/content/model/NX.A29EZ.001) laptop with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 21.10 with all packages up-to-date.

I can connect to a WiFi (home-router or phone hot-spot) without problem initially and surf the net. All fine.

But when I disconnect from the WiFi (either by putting the laptop to sleep or leaving the area or rebooting the router) my laptop is unable to reconnect.

I just shows "connecting to WLAN" and after a while an error notification shows up saying that the connection failed.

Starting this via the WLAN settings page, the little icon on the right of the WLAN name is just spinning forever.

Neither reboot the machine nor turning the WLAN device off and on again (airplane mode) helps.

The output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3" is as follows:

```
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:3802]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's no "Ubuntu 21.10.3". Ubuntu uses YY.MM and, for LTS releases only, a third digit that expresses the point release. Non-LTS releases like 21.10 do NOT get the third digit. Please [edit] your question accordingly and also add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You're right. (I tried 20.04.3 before and there was no network support at all. That's where I had the ".3" from.)